# It's summer time; fizzzzzz!

Tags: riddle

I am cool without the 12,
I am 688,
in fact, I'm ageless,
I existed when dinosaurs breathed.

If you're stuck,
close your eyes and take a deep breath.
There goes your answer,
gone without being seen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are:

> Carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>)

i am cool without the 12

> COOL - L (12th letter) = COO = CO<sub>2</sub>

i am 688

> Atomic numbers: 6=C, 8=O giving COO again

in fact i'm ageless,
I exists when dinosaur breaths.

> Carbon dioxide has been exhaled by creatures into the atmosphere since the age of dinosaurs

take a deep breath.
There's goes your answer,
gone without being seen.

> It's invisible when you breathe out.

fizzzzzz!

> The fizz in soft drinks is carbon dioxide

Comment: Ahh you beat me by 21 seconds, good work

Comment: Darn, beat me to the punch, nice job!

Comment: Darn x2, I guess it's too easy!  Good work!